# properties of class with same termination, that i want to read one by one

Tags: c#, class, properties

Look i really tried to ask very well but maybe i didnt make me understand i have this class

```
public class Deepa
{
    public string Nombre  { get; set; }
    public string capital { get; set; }
    public int x_location { get; set; }
    public int y_location { get; set; }


    public Deepa conexion1 { get; set; }
    public Deepa conexion2 { get; set; }
    public Deepa conexion3 { get; set; }
    public Deepa conexion4 { get; set; }
    public Deepa conexion5 { get; set; }
    public Deepa conexion6 { get; set; }
    public Deepa conexion7 { get; set; }

}
```

and I have created a

```
Deepa Guajira_d   = new Deepa();
```

then I have to setup on each deepa ,on Each connection because always is different

```
// 1. Carga Guajira
Guajira_d.Nombre = Guajira.Name.ToString();
Guajira_d.capital = "Riohacha";
Guajira_d.x_location = Int32.Parse(Guajira.Location.X.ToString());
Guajira_d.y_location = Int32.Parse(Guajira.Location.Y.ToString());

Guajira_d.conexion1 = Magdalena_d;
Guajira_d.conexion2 = Cesar_d;
Guajira_d.conexion3 = null;
Guajira_d.conexion4 = null;
Guajira_d.conexion5 = null;
Guajira_d.conexion6 = null;
Guajira_d.conexion7 = null;
```

now i want to read each connection of the actual deepa like this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    if (Guajira_d.conexion[i] == null) { }
}
```

could you introduce me on how to do it, im really novate with c#

Comment: Instead of having all those separate variables, it looks like you want a `List<Deepa>` or similar.

Comment: You want to access properties, but don't know the name until runtime? You probably want to look at Reflection.

Comment: i tried to create a list but i didnt get it inside a class, how i said im really novate on c#